# App crashes when I change the language from string array

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I am trying to change the language in my dropdown style adapter view which is using a spinner adpater to get the data from a string-array resource. I created two different strings.xml based on locales (one for french and one for english), but when I changed to french and click on the spinner dropdown menu the app crashes.

Below is strings.xml inside default values directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Color Picker</string>
    <string name="new_name">Color Name</string>
    <string name="select">Please select a color</string>
    <string name="color1">Cyan</string>
    <string name="color2">Gray</string>
    <string name="color3">Yellow</string>
    <string name="color4">Green</string>
    <string name="color5">Magenta</string>
    <string name="color6">Blue</string>
    <string name="color7">White</string>
    <string name="color8">Red</string>
    <string-array name="color_array">
        <item>@string/select</item>
        <item>@string/color1</item>
        <item>@string/color2</item>
        <item>@string/color3</item>
        <item>G@string/color4</item>
        <item>@string/color5</item>
        <item>@string/color6</item>
        <item>@string/color7</item>
        <item>@string/color8</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Below is strings.xml inside values-fr-rFR directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Palette de Couleurs</string>
    <string name="new_name">Couleur Choisie</string>
    <string name="select">Choisissez une Couleur</string>
    <string name="color1">Marron</string>
    <string name="color2">Gris</string>
    <string name="color3">Jaune</string>
    <string name="color4">Vert</string>
    <string name="color5">Magenta</string>
    <string name="color6">Bleu</string>
    <string name="color7">Blanc</string>
    <string name="color8">Rouge</string>
    <string-array name="color_array">
        <item>@string/select</item>
        <item>string/color1</item>
        <item>string/color2</item>
        <item>string/color3</item>
        <item>string/color4</item>
        <item>string/color5</item>
        <item>string/color6</item>
        <item>string/color7</item>
        <item>string/color8</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

This is code inside my custom adapter returning my custom view (the views are simple text views)

```
private fun getCustomView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val view: View
    val txt: String = getItem(position).toString()

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(resID, parent, false)

        val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtTextView)
        //txt = list[position]
        textView.text = txt

        setBackground(view, txt, position)

    } else {
        view = convertView
        setBackground(view, txt, position)
    }

    return view
}
```

This is my main activity -- Everything works in English except in in french -- When you click the dropdown on the spinner and select a color, a new activity starts and display the color selected. When language is french, clicking on the spinner automatically crashes the app without a chance to select color

```
val colors = resources.getStringArray(R.array.color_array)

val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.colorSpinner)

spinner?.adapter = (CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_dropdown, colors))

spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener{
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        val color = parent!!.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

        if(position == 0){
            return
        }else{
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, NewActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(COLOR_MESSAGE, color)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here's a stack trace on app crash

```
2020-02-26 18:34:44.476 26860-26887/com.edu.coloractivity E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2020-02-26 18:34:46.681 26860-26860/com.edu.coloractivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.edu.coloractivity, PID: 26860
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
        at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:1400)
        at com.edu.coloractivity.CustomAdapter.setBackground(CustomAdapter.kt:64)
        at com.edu.coloractivity.CustomAdapter.getCustomView(CustomAdapter.kt:35)
        at com.edu.coloractivity.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.kt:42)
        at android.widget.BaseAdapter.getDropDownView(BaseAdapter.java:73)
        at com.edu.coloractivity.CustomAdapter.getDropDownView(CustomAdapter.kt:46)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:994)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:990)
        at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:856)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.computeContentWidth(Spinner.java:1225)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:1251)
        at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:780)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.performClick(AppCompatSpinner.java:443)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: You may want to edit your question and provide the complete stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: In your Color activity are you using the the color names passed from main activity? This may be the issue due to system not able to identify the color based on the names in french.

Comment: Shouldn't it let me at least select the color from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably just typos. 
Inside your color_array in English language you have an item with a G before the @

```
<item>G@string/color4</item>
```

And in French you forgot the @ before 'string' in several items.

```
<item>string/color1</item>
<item>string/color2</item>
<item>string/color3</item>
<item>string/color4</item>
<item>string/color5</item>
<item>string/color6</item>
<item>string/color7</item>
<item>string/color8</item>
```

Try fixing that and see if it helps.